# Handoff icon not disappearing from the phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-watch, handoff

I create a handoff request for my apple watch app with the following code:

```
[self updateUserActivity:@"..." userInfo:selectedTopic webpageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nil]];
```

And I handle the request in the phone AppDelegate with the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
{
    BOOL handled = NO;
    [userActivity becomeCurrent];
    NSString *type = [userActivity activityType];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [userActivity userInfo];
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"..."]) {
        //does action
        [userActivity invalidate];
        handled = YES;
    }
    return handled;
}
```

The issue is the handoff icon does not go away even though this code is executed. What am I doing wrong here? **Why will the handoff icon not disappear?**

I've seen this behaviour on other applications. The only applications I see with the correct behaviour are native apps.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Ecarrion No, I wasn't able to resolve the issue. I found that happens for other third party apps. only native apps seem to have it working.